# How to abolish functions on github/pypi project

Tags: github, pypi, deprecation-warning

I have a GitHub/Pypi project ([wexpect](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect)). There are some methods in this project which are supposed to be unused. I want to clean up my project, by removing these functions, however I'm not sure that they are really unused or not. My best idea is to printout huge *deprecated* message (Then I wait feedback, if they are in use, Then delete them)

But are there any better way to abolish those functions?

Is there any way collect coverage/usage of all functions in real (end-user) usage?

Comment: The standard way to deprecate is to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html. You can only get end-user usage information if you make it phone home, which may not be popular. Alternatively I suppose you could search the code bases of known users (e.g. https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/network/dependents) for use of those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would make a minor/patch release which adds warnings that these functions are internal or deprecated, and then make a major release which actually removes them.

However, if you have a documented API (looks like you do) it would be reasonable to change any function that's not part of this documented API. Developers shouldn't be dependent on internal or undocumented features or functions.